# Can we take the derivative of functionals on the space of smooth scalar fields of a riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Is it possible to take the derivative of a functional $ \mathcal{L}:\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, where $\mathcal{F} = \{f:\mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}|f \: is \: smooth\} $. We know the riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$. We would like to derive the derivative of some simple functionals(like the evaluation functional) that depend on the riemanian metric tensor. Also I would appreciate some references for further reading.

Comment: Derivative with respect to what? In any case, it sounds like the thing you wish to define is known as the [distributional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Differentiation_of_distributions), though some care must be taken with the subtleties of infinite-dimensional vector spaces like $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Derivative of $\mathcal{L}[f]$ wrt to the scalar field/function f. If $\mathcal{M}$ were euclidean, then this would be the functional derivative for eg if  $\mathcal{L}[f] = \lVert f \rVert^2$, then $\nabla \mathcal{L}[f] = 2 f $. I would like something that can take the Riemannian metric of $\mathcal{M}$ into account when computing this derivative.

Comment: In that case you're talking about calculus of variations, and the appropriate notion is the [Gateaux derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative) (with respect to the Frechet topology on $\mathcal{F}=C^\infty M$). The Riemannian metric isn't involved unless $\mathcal{L}$ also depends on the metric.

Comment: How about a concrete example of a functional you want to differentiate? In general, you can always do it formally and find the Euler-Lagrange equation. After that you have to do some work to get some useful results from it. That's usually highly dependent on the specific situation.

Comment: Sure, I am interested in two functionals in particular. One is the evaluation functional $\mathcal{L}_x[f] = f(x)$, and the other one is  $\mathcal{L}_{(x_1,..,x_n)}[f] = \sum_{i=1}^n \lVert f(x_i) - y_i \rVert^2 $. I know that $x_i \in \mathcal{M}$, I would like to know how the functional derivative would depend on the riemannian structure of $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: @HRI Neither of those functionals depend on the Riemannian structure at all, so neither would their derivatives. One can compute their derivatives straightforwardly from the difference quotient:$$D\mathcal{L}[f,g]:=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\mathcal{L}[f+\epsilon g]-\mathcal{L}[f]}{\epsilon}$$

Comment: What about the following functional: $\mathcal{L}[f] = \int_{x \in \mathcal{M}} \lVert f(x) - y(x) \rVert^2 dx$, where $y$ is some known fixed function. Does this depend on the Riemannian structure? Thinking about the example of $S^1$ and $[0,1)$ I can see how the former examples are independent of the Riemannian structure but in this case, I think it is.

Comment: @HRI That depends on what you mean by $dx$. In order to integrate a smooth function on a manifold, one needs choose a suitable measure. The standard choice is the [Riemann measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Riemannian_volume_form) (typically denoted $dV_g$ or $\omega_g$), which *does* depend  on the metric. In that case, one can differentiate w.r.t. the metric $g$ by considering $\mathcal{L}$ to be a functional with multiple arguments $\mathcal{L}[f,g]$ and differentiate in the same way.